# jQuery trigger before listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, triggers

With `$(document).ready();`  you can execute it AFTER dom is ready but it will still fire.

How can I get a custom trigger to behave in the same way?

i.e.

```
$(document).trigger("myEvent");
```

As the page is loading (before myEvent), I might lazy load a script, do some Ajax, and when Ajax is complete (now possibly after myEvent), I'd place a listener in the Ajax callback to make sure myEvent as happened before I proceed (like you might do with a $(document).ready())

```
$(document).on("myEvent", function(){ ... });
```

But obviously this won't fire because it was triggered before the listener was in place.

Comment: Do you need something like `.when()` ?http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: I'm not sure i understand what you are looking for, you want to trigger event as soon as event is bound or before? If it is before, doesn't make much sense actually for me. Could you tell us what is supposed to do your event? BTW, you could check in jquery source how it is done for ready 'pseudo' event, using readyList deferred object.

Comment: @Cԃաԃ Using Deferred makes sense.

Comment: @roasted The listener may or may not be registered before the event is triggered, like how you can listen for dom ready before or after that event, but as you point out it's different from all other events, and uses deferred.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger event **before** it is bound will of course have no effect.

You should trigger it only after some handler is attached to it otherwise nothing will be fired. 
Regarding the ready event, jQuery use a deferred object for that, the 'readyList' object. But i'm quite sure it is just oversized for what you are looking for and anyway this is still fired depending other events, DOMContentLoaded or onreadystatechange or onload of window object or resolved manually using a timeout if these events are already done.

So why not trigger event once you have bound it, the classic way:

```
$(document).on("myEvent", function(){ /**/ }).trigger('myEvent');
```

If for some reason you want to fired it in specific case and, for obscur reason you cannot modify ajax callback method to check for some condition, you could still use the ajaxStop() handler, something like that:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function () {
    if ($._data(document, 'events').myEvent) {
        $(this).trigger('myEvent').off('ajaxStop'); //off() could be removed, depending your needs
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tAnrh/)

If you want to use the promise interface returned by your ajax method, use something like that:

```
$.when($.get('myajax')).done(function(){$(document).trigger('myEvent')});
```

But really, you don't tell us enough what you are looking for, maybe your logic is failing somewhere else and a better approach should be possible IMO.